# My app is crashing with no exception "HandleSigQuit DumpForSigQuit"

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am getting bulk data from server.
On parsing on Android 8 Oreo (OnePlus 3T).
It shows Application not responding. And the options to kill or wait is given.
If I do not answer to the dialog, the app closes without any exception.
The only thing I get in logs is

`E/zygote: # HandleSigQuit # DumpForSigQuit # before # pid=12345`

The same app is working fine on devices with lower Android versions.

How to ask for wait programatically ?

Comment: Somehow you are trying to fetch data on UI thread.

Comment: You are doing a long running operation at the UI Thread, you need to look the code based on the behaviour since those type of error doesn't have a stacktrace

Comment: If the data to parse is big you should consider doing it in an AscynTask as well the fetching.

Comment: Thank you guys for guiding in right direction. Eventually I figured out that the previous developer was doing response.contains("error") on 3,00,000 lines of response in onPostExecute method of the async task.